# Is there an inyan to shake the lulav in the sukka, even when it's raining?

Tags: halacha, sukkah, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, arizal, practical-kabbalah

According to the Arizal one should shake the lulav in the sukka al pi kabbala. Does this inyan apply even if it's raining in the sukka?

Answer (score 1):

The Lubavitcher Rebbe (Likkutei Sichos 22 [p. 125](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15952&st=&pgnum=139)) suggests it would be best to wait for the rain to stop, even though the obligation of sukkah is suspended, because shaking lulav in the sukkah is not just part of the general mitzvah of residing in the sukkah, but an enhancement of the mitzvah of lulav itself.

Comment: That logic seems backwards. Only if you are trying to enhance sukkah would it matter if the sukkah is kosher

Comment: @DoubleAA Not sure what you mean. I didn't say anything about a non-kosher sukkah.

Comment: There are rishonim who view a booth with rain coming in as not a kosher sukkah, but anyway I just meant "...would it matter if there is sukkah-dwelling occurring".

Comment: @DoubleAA As I understand, it's the **mitzvah** of sukkah that complements the mitzvah of lulav, so you would want to wait for the obligation to resume. But the point is not about when to shake so much as where to shake. If it were an aspect of sukkah-dwelling, it would be suspended by the rain and you could do it indoors, just like eating and sleeping. Because it's an aspect of lulav-shaking, it applies independently of your current sukkah status.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I beleive this is true according to Teshuvos vHanhagos by Rabbi Moshe Shternbuch, I will add the exact refference when I can find it. (after YT). (I think it is in his discussion of how the kabbalistic connection between sukka and lulav overides "tadir vsheino tadir"

Comment: This would be surprising since R' Sternbuch in Moadim Uzmanim vol 2 argues against shaking the lulav in the sukkah at all (unless you happen to have one at shul and have time to go out and shake it there just before hallel).